# How can I remove Gnome Desktop Environment without messing Unity DE? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: unity, gnome, uninstall, desktop-environments

I need to get rid of the GNOME Desktop Environment which has been installed by default when I updated my pc from 15.10 to 16.04.

After a while, I found myself not only with GNOME DE, but also with Cinnamon alongside (in the login screen, I could choose at least five or six DE!)

Now I am using Unity, and I'm happy with that, and I successfully uninstalled Cinnamon, but now I'm afraid that after uninstalling GNOME I will mess up the Unity DE, since I see many packages running in unity with the packagename starting with gnome-... Would someone mind to help me? Thx in advance

Answer (score 44):

To be honest it would be better to back up for files and all config files in the Home folder and do a fresh install of Ubunutu.

If not try this:

Start by running this command:

**Uninstall just ubuntu-gnome-desktop**

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
```

This will remove just the ubuntu-gnome-desktop package itself.

**Uninstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop and it's dependencies**

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

This will remove the ubuntu-gnome-desktop package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed.

**Purging your config/data too**

If you also want to delete your local/config files for ubuntu-gnome-desktop then this will work.

*Caution! Purged config/data can not be restored by reinstalling the package.*

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Or similarly, like this ubuntu-gnome-desktop

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

to remove extra packages and dependencies no longer needed on your system.

You might (or might not, depending on if gdm was removed already) need to use these commands to change your login screen back to Unity's default (which is lightDM) run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Hit enter at the prompt and then select lightdm from the options. After that you can remove gdm with

```
sudo apt-get remove gdm
```

Finally run:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

INFO [HERE](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/u/ubuntu-gnome-desktop/uninstall/index.html) and [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hyGNZekSmQ)

Comment: Thx, if something goes wrong I will repost and update the situation

Comment: Done it, the gnome-ubuntu-desktop wasn't inside my pc already, but when I tried to log out and then checked the ubuntu logo (unity de by default) I still saw that I could choose between 4 total DE: Unity, Gnome, Gnome (Compiz), Gnome(Meta-something now I can't remember). Can you still help me?

Comment: Try sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell

Comment: When I try this I have a problem: I can't login to ubuntu.

I solved this problem when I change my default desktop environment from gnome to unity.

Comment: My problem was memory consuming of gnome hence removed it by this answer then `reboot` the system to stop the related process. The memory usage reduced by approximately 4.2GB of ram.

Answer (score 7):

You can see all Gnome package list by :

```
apt list --installed | grep gnome
```

then remove your arbitary package by :

```
apt-get remove <package name>
```

or remove all packages by:

```
sudo apt-get remove $(apt list --installed "gnome*" 2>/dev/null | awk -F'/' 'NR>1{print $1}')
```

Comment: works great! thank you :)

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

I also like the user interface of Unity desktop environment, so try these beautiful steps...

**Step 1 :** This will remove all gnome related things.

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus nautilus-* gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-termina* gnome-pane* gnome-applet* gnome-bluetooth gnome-desktop* gnome-sessio* gnome-user* gnome-shell-common zeitgeist-core libzeitgeist* gnome-control-center gnome-screenshot gnome* && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**Step 2 :** This will remove all snap applications, if you don't do this step then you will see that there are 2 same apps some app (like 2 system-monitors, 2 terminals, 2 calculators etc) after installing unity. so run bellow code without any worry.

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

**Step 3 :** Now connect your system to a WI-FI to install *Unity* .

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

**Step 4 :** After successful installation, reboot your system.
You may have a problem that tap to click not working after replacing Gnome with Unity.
If so then run below code to solve that problem..

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Now reboot your system and Login again.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your system and press Control-Alt-F1 to get to a text terminal. Log in there and type the following:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm

Comment: For what?! Question is about removing the gnome. not installing it!

Answer (score 0):

## First, check what is going to be removed

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep .gnome.
```

## If you are ok with it, run this command

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge gnome*
```

## Command explanation

```
# dpkg -l       lists all installed packages
# grep .gnome.   filters, so that only packages with keyword gnome within their names, listed
# purge         removes mentioned package
# autoremove    tries to remove dependency packages
```