# How to set unity as default after installing ubuntu-gnome-desktop in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, gnome, 16.04, gdm

Recently I installed gnome-desktop in my Unity Ubuntu 16.04.Now I want to set my Unity desktop environment as default.

I installed Gnome by using these commands :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

then chose gdm3 as default.

Now, I have searched on internet how to do so, one of them say this :

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu
```

But it throws error saying :

> sudo: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults: command not found

I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You don't have to do that. Lightdm, or whatever is used, should remember the last option selected. Select Unity at login once, and Unity will be the default, until another option is selected.

Comment: If you dont want gnome follow this steps and then restart the pc.
https://askubuntu.com/a/767582

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file ( if it doesn't exist - create it. File must be owned by root )

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=unity
```

That will make unity default for all users, but remember what mikewhatever said: if you choose a specific session once, login screen will remember it.