# Problems after returning back to Unity from GNOME

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome

I have pretty much the same problem as described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793504/how-to-set-unity-as-default-after-installing-ubuntu-gnome-desktop-in-ubuntu-16-0). I installed GNOME desktop environment on Ubuntu 16.04 using the command

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

But before that I've done this

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell
```

And now I want to go back to the Unity desktop environment. I changed default display manager back to the `lightdm` from `gdm3` using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and choosing `lightdm`. After that I rebooted the system and saw that boot logo didn't change back to standard. On the login screen I chose Unity desktop environment (`Ubuntu`) but there are some strange things now:

- system font didn't change to what was in Unity
- I can't use the desktop (i.e. there are no files/folders and there is no response to mouse clicks on desktop at all
- after reboot the default desktop environment is still GNOME despite that I was choosing Unity every time (Ubuntu remembers my last choice but GNOME is the first in the list and there is "(default)" after its name).
- also there are some changes in context menus style.

I tried to do what is said in similar questions, namely:

- Setting theme (Appearance -> Theme) to `Ambiance`. However it was already selected. Though `Adwaita` is default.
- Removing `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`
- Creating a config file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with the following content:

  ```
  [SeatDefaults]
  user-session=unity
  ```

There is a screentshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` with `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` which is the base meta package for Unity DE.

Comment: @Videonauth unfortunately, I have already done `sudo apt remove --purge gnome-shell` and then I did `sudo apt autoremove` and this worked. Don't know if the last one did help but it freed good amount of memory and there were some packages concerning the GNOME such as `ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers`, `ubuntu-gnome-default-settings` and some else. However the boot logo remained the same. Though I find this logo pretty good and I'm not sure whether I want to change it.
But I need to clarify. Will I lose my Unity settings after reinstalling Unity?