# Removing gnome from Ubuntu 18.04 after changing to KDE Plasma

Tags: 18.04, gnome, kde

I have recently switched from Win10 to Ubuntu 18.04. I decided to switch to the KDE Plasma DE, using the instructions on this page:

https://vitux.com/how-to-install-the-kde-plasma-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

I'm loving KDE and don't have any plans to use gnome again. So I followed the instructions on this page:

[How can I remove Gnome Desktop Environment without messing Unity DE? (Ubuntu 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767577/how-can-i-remove-gnome-desktop-environment-without-messing-unity-de-ubuntu-16)

However, when I enter the first command in konsole, I get the following response:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Package 'ubuntu-gnome-desktop' is not
>   installed, so not removed 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to
>   remove and 0 not to upgrade.

And when I enter the second, I get:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Package 'gnome-shell' is not installed, so
>   not removed 0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to
>   upgrade.

Does this mean the installation automatically removed gnome?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same question and found this https://superuser.com/a/134696/200565

Apparently we can use `tasksel` to also uninstall one of the environments, I have not tried yet but it would be like `sudo tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop`.