# Ubuntu 18.04 keyboard input lag

Tags: keyboard

Hi I recently bought a new computer and installed ubuntu 18.04 on my desktop.

Things okay when I type on Windows Os.

But when I type my keyboard in ubuntu OS on everywhere including terminal, chrome, etc, the texts do not appear right after typing and appear with delay.

I searched solution and checked slow key and Setting > Universal Access > Typing but I think the problem is not related to these settings.

Is there any way to fix these lagging problem?

---

- I checked AccessX but it was already off and my computer specification is i7-10700k, msi z490 unify, rtx2080 super. and my key board is USB connected and model is cherry mx board 3.0s. I checked every USB port but nothing changed and did not check other keyboard models to my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the past on fresh installs
At a terminal type

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

If no luck then try this;
[Remove the default gnome desktop and try unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767577/how-can-i-remove-gnome-desktop-environment-without-messing-unity-de-ubuntu-16)

Sorry this first attempt didn't work for you
Open a terminal and type `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=0`

This is only temporary until you reboot so don't worry.

Comment: sorry nothing changed. What kind of info you want which would be helpful to solve this problem? I reinstalled ubuntu but things are same

Comment: Fist in Universal Access check that Typing Assist (AccessX) is off so that nothing can be selected there. Second tell us what computer it is, if it's a USB connected keyboard or other.

Comment: I checked AccessX but it was already off and my computer specification is i7-10700k, msi z490 unify, rtx2080 super. and my key board is USB connected and model is cherry mx board 3.0s. I checked every USB port but nothing changed and did not check other keyboard models to my desktop.