# Why does my UI look like this

Tags: gui

I recently powered on my laptop only to be greeted to this UI

[image: this UI]

I'm not sure if i installed something to make this happen. Im using the latest Ubuntu 20.04.1 version and i'm confused as to why the gui looks like the 12.04 version of ubuntu

Comment: What did it used to look like before you did something you're not sure of?  There are a lot of possible user options, so it's hard to know what changed for you.

Comment: It used to look like the normal gui from when i installed it on my laptop for the first time

Comment: Well, based on your edit, it's because you installed a new desktop environment. You can log out and change it on the login screen. To remove GNOME, maybe this could help (https://askubuntu.com/questions/767577/how-can-i-remove-gnome-desktop-environment-without-messing-unity-de-ubuntu-16)