# Are Unity and Gnome conflicting? What's wrong with my desktop environment?

Tags: apt, unity, gnome, shutdown

I restarted my computer one day and found a bunch of my unity settings and windows were screwed up (I'll show pictures in a moment). Thinking a bad shutdown had just corrupted settings or something, I backed up all my files, made a fresh `20.04` boot image, and reinstalled the os. But then after getting everything back how I wanted it, it happened again!

I went through this process several times, until I finally decided to document exactly what I did and see where things got messed up.

So I followed this exact process:

- Reinstall the operating system. I intentionally did not select the option to "download updates while installing".
- In gnome do these commands:

```bsh
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
sudo shutdown -r now
```

The desktop environment now looks like this, which is correct:

[image: correct environment]

- Do other steps to get things how I want them, to see which one breaks things.

```bsh
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Still fine.

```bsh
sudo apt remove gnome-shell
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Still fine.

But then updating all software breaks things.

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Now the environment looks like this:

[image: broken environment]

[image: broken environment]

Numerous other little things also aren't working, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal, I can't change the wallpaper anymore, and the hardware <kbd>fn</kbd> switches such as for screen brightness don't work. Also, after logging in the mouse cursor blinks some exact number of times in a way it doesn't when the environment is correct.

It's difficult to say what about the updated software is doing this, since after a fresh install more than a hundred packages need to be updated. However this problem only started a few weeks ago.

I've tried doing things like suggested in these question to entirely remove gnome, but they've either had no effect or made things worse.

- [How can I remove Gnome Desktop Environment without messing Unity DE? (Ubuntu 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767577/how-can-i-remove-gnome-desktop-environment-without-messing-unity-de-ubuntu-16)
- [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ)

I also tried to use the [unity-specific distribution of ubuntu](http://ubuntuunity.org/), and even that was having the same problem!

Also, reinstalling `gnome-shell` I would say made it worse :(

[image]

What can I do to figure out what's going on? It seems like some of the old gnome icons and themes are "sneaking back in" somehow, but I have no idea if that's a reasonable guess. I don't even know where to start debugging this.

This is a Dell XPS 15 9570, which I learned by running `sudo dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'`. I have another computer, a Dell XPS 15 7590 that isn't having these same problems.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this, but if you want to use Unity, use the distro tailored for it. http://ubuntuunity.org/ (BTW, it is not supported in this site. There is a telegram group for support).

Comment: I actually already tried that :( I encountered the exact same problem. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Then report it to their telegram/matrix group. They may know what is going on. Unity might partially depend on GNOME shell.

Comment: I'll try reinstalling it and see what happens!

Comment: I'd say that made it worse :( I added a screenshot to demonstrate.

Comment: `ctrl+alt+t` to open the terminal not working had just ringed a bell for me. You have already wasted so much time, you could as well look [at this post of mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/1318540/1157519) quickly, to see whether it could serve with a new spark of inspiration for your investigation...